# Put time in Date/Time fireld

Tags: vba, ms-access, time

I am trying to update logout date of particular user but it shows error like.

Error:

> No Value Given For One Or More Required Parameters.

I am using below code.

```
Source = "UPDATE timetbl Set logouttime = tmp where empname = 'Prashant'"
.Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
MsgBox "success"
```

explaination: `tmp` (variable) has a current IST Time i.e `10:5:19 PM` (without single quote), it update in `logouttime` field (date/time) when `empname` is `Prashant`.

Note: It works when I manually put `tmp` value i.e `'10:5:19 PM'` but it doesn't work without quote.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      Source = "UPDATE timetbl Set logouttime =#" & tmp & "# where empname = 'Prashant'"
     .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
      MsgBox "success"
```

You have to use variables like this. And dates need # on both sides for access sql

Comment: Thank you very much Doug...this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Prush if this satisfied youre criteria please mark it as answered